Problem with circuit--ESP showing invalid packet header on powering the robot on by battery
I am trying to build a self-balancing robot, the circuit of which I have attached here. Now I am facing an issue, which is when I power the ESP via the 5V buck convertor output, the ESP gets corrupted and it shows an invalid packet header in the serial output. When I don't connect the ESP to any 5V output and just power it directly via the USB through my laptop, everything seems to work fine. I think the problem might be due to my circuit not being ground properly, but since I am quite a newbie to circuits and everything, I am not able to pinpoint the problem. Can anyone please take a look at my circuit and tell me what the problem might be?


Are you aware that ESP-32's are powered from 3V or 3.3V?

@MichaelKaras Some of the modules for esp32 have a LDO onboard to provide the 3.3V

@Aaron - Yes on the modules to which the ESP-32 is mounted it is very common to find an LDO or a small buck converter to convert power sources such as USB-5V, LiPo Battery 3.7->4.2V or external 5V to the 3V or 3.3V used by the ESP-32. I am not aware of any Expressif ESP-32's that directly take in 5V to the component itself. My original comment/question was aimed at the question asker who has shown a diagram with 5V going directly to the ESP-32. If they have their circuit actually wired up like that the ESP-32 is likely damaged.

Hi, @MichaelKaras, I am using a NodeMCU-ESP32s, the pinout diagram of which is as shown here:
https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp32/docs/nodemcu-32s_product_specification.pdf
So, I think it can take 5V power input.

@ShivanshChaudhary - That is a module called a NodeMCU-32S. It has an ESP-32 chip on it. Yes the module can take in 5V as a power source. You would to well to change your block diagram to show NodeMCU-32S to correctly depict what you are hooking up.
